# Extract just the names of the files from archive using Apache Tika

Tags: java, apache, parsing, apache-tika

I want Tika to output only the names of the files within the archive (if the input file is an archive) and the file content as usual if the input file is not an archive. How can I do that?

Comment: I googled a lot. No results. Even looked at the tika source code in github to get an idea. Couldn't figure out myself.

Comment: I got an answer in their mailing list. I'm going to try that out.

Comment: How are you using Tika? From Java? Tika CLI? Tika Server?

Comment: From Java. Anyways I have figured out myself by looking at Tika's source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I extended the ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor class

```
class CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor extends ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor {
  public CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(ParseContext context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public void parseEmbedded(
        InputStream stream, ContentHandler handler, Metadata metadata, boolean outputHtml)
        throws SAXException, IOException {


    String name = metadata.get(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY);
    if (name != null && name.length() > 0 ) {
        handler.startElement(XHTML, "h1", "h1", new AttributesImpl());
        char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
        handler.characters(chars, 0, chars.length);
        handler.endElement(XHTML, "h1", "h1");
    }

    //Removed the parsing logic here.. We just want the file names..

  }
}
```

and set it to the ParseContext variable before doing `someparser.parse()`

```
context.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, new CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(this.context));
```

This works only for zip, tar and jar. That's enough for me.

Comment: Thank-you for following up with the solution you found. I need the ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor to throw an exception (rather than swallowing it) when an embedded document fails and this has been very helpful.